# Parsing JSON string into record in Haskell

Tags: json, parsing, haskell

I'm struggling to understand this (I'm still a bit new to Haskell) but I'm finding the documentation for the `Text.JSON` package to be a little confusing. Basically I have this data record type: -

```
data Tweet = Tweet
    {
        from_user :: String,
        to_user_id :: String,
        profile_image_url :: String,
        created_at :: String,
        id_str :: String,
        source :: String,
        to_user_id_str :: String,
        from_user_id_str :: String,
        from_user_id :: String,
        text :: String,
        metadata :: String
    }
```

and I have some tweets in JSON format that conform to the structure of this type. The thing that I'm struggling with is how to map the above to what gets returned from the following code

```
decode tweet :: Result JSValue
```

into the above datatype. I understand that I'm supposed to create an instance of `instance JSON Tweet` but I don't know where to go from there.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to write a `showJSON` and `readJSON` method, for your type, that builds your Haskell values out of the JSON format. The JSON package will take care of parsing the raw string into a [`JSValue`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/json/0.4.4/doc/html/src/Text-JSON-Types.html#JSValue) for you.

Your tweet will be a `JSObject` containing a map of strings, most likely.

- Use `show` to look at the JSObject, to see how the fields are laid out.
- You can lookup each field using `get_field` on the `JSObject`.
- You can use `fromJSString` to get a regular Haskell strings from a `JSString`.

Broadly, you'll need something like,

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}

import Text.JSON
import Text.JSON.Types

instance JSON Tweet where

    readJSON (JSObject o) = return $ Tweet { .. }
            where from_user         = grab o "from_user"
                  to_user_id        = grab o "to_user_id"
                  profile_image_url = grab o "proile_image_url"
                  created_at        = grab o "created_at"
                  id_str            = grab o "id_str"
                  source            = grab o "source"
                  to_user_id_str    = grab o "to_user_id_str"
                  from_user_id_str  = grab o "from_user_id_str"
                  from_user_id      = grab o "from_user_id"
                  text              = grab o "text"
                  metadata          = grab o "metadata"


grab o s = case get_field o s of
                Nothing            -> error "Invalid field " ++ show s
                Just (JSString s') -> fromJSString s'
```

Note, I'm using the rather cool wild cards language extension.

Without an example of the JSON encoding, there's not much more I can advise.

---

*Related*

You can find example instances for the JSON encoding via instances

- [in the source](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/json/0.4.4/doc/html/src/Text-JSON.html#JSON), for 
  simple types. Or in other packages that depend on json.
- An instance for AUR messages [is here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/archlinux/0.3.3/doc/html/src/Distribution-ArchLinux-AUR.html#AURInfo), as a (low level) example.

Comment: Superb, thanks for the detailed reply that worked a treat. Is there any way I can talk to the package authors to perhaps put examples like this (with credit to you obviously) in the documentation?

Answer (score 24):

I'd recommend that you use the new [aeson](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson) package instead of the [json](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/json) package, as the former performs much better. Here's how you'd convert a JSON object to a Haskell record, using aeson:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Example where

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Data.Aeson

data Tweet = Tweet {
    from_user :: String,
    to_user_id :: String,
    profile_image_url :: String,
    created_at :: String,
    id_str :: String,
    source :: String,
    to_user_id_str :: String,
    from_user_id_str :: String,
    from_user_id :: String,
    text :: String,
    metadata :: String
    }

instance FromJSON Tweet where
    parseJSON (Object v) =
        Tweet <$> v .: "from_user"
              <*> v .: "to_user_id"
              <*> v .: "profile_image_url"
              <*> v .: "created_at"
              <*> v .: "id_str"
              <*> v .: "source"
              <*> v .: "to_user_id_str"
              <*> v .: "from_user_id_str"
              <*> v .: "from_user_id"
              <*> v .: "text"
              <*> v .: "metadata"
    -- A non-Object value is of the wrong type, so use mzero to fail.
    parseJSON _          = mzero
```

Then use `Data.Aeson.json` to get a [attoparsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec) parser that converts a `ByteString` into a `Value`. The call `fromJSON` on the `Value` to attempt to parse it into your record. Note that there are two different parsers involved in these two steps, a `Data.Attoparsec.Parser` parser for converting the `ByteString` into a generic JSON `Value` and then a `Data.Aeson.Types.Parser` parser for converting the JSON value into a record. Note that both steps can fail:

- The first parser can fail if the `ByteString` isn't a valid JSON value.
- The second parser can fail if the (valid) JSON value doesn't contain one of the fields you mentioned in your `fromJSON` implementation.

The aeson package prefers the new Unicode type `Text` (defined in the [text](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text) package) to the more old school `String` type. The `Text` type has a much more memory efficient representation than `String` and generally performs better. I'd recommend that you change the `Tweet` type to use `Text` instead of `String`.

If you ever need to convert between `String` and `Text`, use the `pack` and `unpack` functions defined in `Data.Text`. Note that such conversions require O(n) time, so avoid them as much as possible (i.e. always use `Text`).

Answer (score 4):

Import Data.JSon.Generic and Data.Data, then add deriving (Data) to your record type, and then try using decodeJSON on the tweet.

Comment: I'm trying to do this, but can't find `Data.JSon.Generic`.  Could you point me to it?

Comment: It is possible he meant Data.Aeson.Generic: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/aeson/0.6.0.2/doc/html/Data-Aeson-Generic.html

Answer (score 1):

I support the answer by @tibbe.
However, I would like to add how to provide default values if the arguments are missing in the JSON provided.

In tibbe's answer you can do the following:

```
Tweet <$> v .: "from_user"
      <*> v .:? "to_user_id"       .!= "some user here"
      <*> v .: "profile_image_url" .!= "url to image"
      <*> v .: "created_at"
      <*> v .: "id_str"             .!= 232131
      <*> v .: "source"
```

This will take default parameters while parsing the JSON.